# How do I set legacy_connection_handling to false in my Rails application?

Tags: model-view-controller, activerecord

Please set
`legacy_connection_handling` to `false` in your application.

Can someone please help with this. It tells me to set it to false but I'm new to coding and I have no idea how to go about that.

Can

```
 % bundle exec rspec
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using legacy connection handling is deprecated. Please set
`legacy_connection_handling` to `false` in your application.

The new connection handling does not support `connection_handlers`
getter and setter.

Read more about how to migrate at: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#migrate-to-the-new-connection-handling
 (called from <top (required)> at /Users/a/rails-activerecord-models-and-rails-readme/config/environment.rb:5)
No examples found.


Finished in 0.00019 seconds (files took 0.94409 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures
```

This is what's in my environment.rb file

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

I've went to the website it told me to I think maybe there is something wrong in my file (it was already generated to be like that) It has Rails.application.initialize! but I'm not sure how to set that as false.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the version of Rails you're using, this can be done by adding the change to your `application.rb` or individual environment files for production, staging, testing, etc. (might look something like `config/environments/production.rb`, etc.)

From the docs linked in the error message: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#migrate-to-the-new-connection-handling

You can open your `application.rb` file and add the following to fix the issue:

```
config.active_record.legacy_connection_handling = false
```